# java swing - how to change window background

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I was trying to make a button that switches the window background from default to red.
I haven't found any preset colors to match the default so i tried to get it from `panel.getBackground` when i created it. I have an error at `line 11`, i don't know how to check the current background color.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 262);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setVisible(true);
    Color c=panel.getBackground();

    JButton btnRed = new JButton("Red");
    btnRed.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(panel.getBackground(c));{
                panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
            else{
                panel.setBackground(c);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't use a `null` layout to start with.

Comment: `if(panel.getBackground(c));{`?  Does your code actually compile?

Comment: @MadProgrammer This would actually compile

Comment: buddy it's not  JS or AS. its Java. strong type. please care about this

Comment: @SamTebbs33 Along with the `else` statement, I don't think so.  And I'm not aware of any `getBackground(Color)` method

Comment: @MadProgrammer You're right actually, removing the else statement does let it compile.

Comment: @SamTebbs33 Even with the fact that their is no such method as `getBackground(Color)` and if we assume they meant `getBackground()`, it returns a `Color`, which means that the `if` statement won't evaluate to a `boolean` result?  It won't compile :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, when I was talking about it compiling, I meant the if-statement structure, I didn't consider the actual method being used :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to compare the `Color`, this is an `Object` so `equals()` is the way... also an `if` expects a `boolean` and will finish when `;` is found, so this:

```
if(panel.getBackground(c));{
// ↑ not a boolean        ↑
//                        ↑
//                        ; is wrong
```

must be

```
if(panel.getBackground().equals(c)){
```

Comment: What about `panel.getBackground().equals(c)`?

Comment: Phhh ... `getBackground` is a _method_ that returns the current background color. As a method, it should have parantheses: `panel.getBackground().equals(c)`. OPs code snippet didn't compile. Neither d̶o̶e̶s̶  did yours.

Comment: You might like to also mention that there is also no such method as `getBackground(Color)`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I might... and you?

Comment: @JordiCastilla I think I've had enough of a whinge :P

Answer (score 2):

`if(panel.getBackground(c));{` isn't correct, it won't even compile.  It should be `if (c.equals(panel.getBackground()) {`

Note, the lack of `;` at the end of the statement.

Also, there is no such method as `getBackground(Color)`, so, along with the `else` statement, your code basically wouldn't compile.

Don't use `null` layouts, you don't control the aspects of the UI which will change the components required sizes on different systems or look and feel settings

```
  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.Dimension;
  import java.awt.EventQueue;
  import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.UIManager;
  import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

  public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
          }

          JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          frame.setContentPane(new TestPane());
          frame.pack();
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          frame.setVisible(true);
        }
      });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

      private Color baseColor;

      public TestPane() {
        baseColor = getBackground();
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JButton btn = new JButton("Click");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (baseColor.equals(getBackground())) {
              setBackground(Color.RED);
            } else {
              setBackground(baseColor);
            }
          }
        });

        add(btn);
      }

      @Override
      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
      }

    }

  }
```

An alternative to checking the current color, which might cause some issues on some systems/look and feels would be to use a simple counter...

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

  private int tick;

  public TestPane() {
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    JButton btn = new JButton("Click");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tick++;
        if ((tick % 2) != 0) {
          setBackground(Color.RED);
        } else {
          setBackground(null);
        }
      }
    });

    add(btn);
  }

  @Override
  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(200, 200);
  }

}
```

This would allow you to flip the state independently of the current the color which would generally be safer